# JavaScript/Ajax -- document load, some controls not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a little complicated, but let me try to sum-up. I have two sets of Javascript code that use AJAX and JSON (and PHP and ...) to get specific data and load a set of controls. In one case, called from a click event handler all the controls are loaded properly with the correct data, all is well. In the second, when the page first loads (called properly, the code does execute when the page loads and it does return values), unless I add an alert() dialog in the code, several controls do not actually get loaded. If the alert() is in the function, the controls are loaded. This is, to put it mildly, confusing.

The code that **doesn't** work is identical to the code that does. Here's the code called when the form loads:

```
function getFirstAward()
  {
     // this has to go get the first award at the top of the list
     // (sort order) by rank and date, and return that to the entryfields:
     var namecode = document.getElementById("namecode").value;

     // now we need to set up the Ajax code to return just this specific
     // award, and stuff it into the fields above ..
     $.ajax
     ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $admin_html_RootPath; ?>lookups/returnFirstAward.php",
        data: { 'namecode' : namecode },
        dataType: "json", // return value is json array
        //cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
// why is this necessary? 
//alert( "First Award in List loaded" );
           // first get the data array and break it up ...
           document.getElementById("awardcode").value        = data[0];
           document.getElementById("currentaward").value     = data[1];
           getAwards();
           document.getElementById("awardnumber").value      = data[2];
           document.getElementById("awarddate").value        = data[3]; 
           document.getElementById("eventname").value        = data[4];
           document.getElementById("region").value           = data[5];
           // Barony ... is it empty? If not, enable it, and set the value
           if ( data[6] != "" )
           {
              document.getElementById("barony").disabled     = false;
              document.getElementById("barony").value        = data[6];
           }
           else
           {
              // empty, enable, set value to empty, and disable it
              document.getElementById("barony").disabled     = false;
              document.getElementById("barony").value        = "";
              document.getElementById("barony").disabled     = true;
           }
           document.getElementById("royalcode").value        = data[7];
           // this one is necessary because of the way the code for getRoyals works:
           document.getElementById("currentroyalcode").value = data[7];
           getRoyals();

           document.getElementById("notes").value            = data[8];
           tinymce.get('notes').setContent(data[8]);
           document.getElementById("laurelprimary").value   = data[9];
           tinymce.get('laurelprimary').setContent(data[9]);
           document.getElementById("laurelsecondary").value = data[10];
           tinymce.get('laurelsecondary').setContent(data[10]);

           // set focus on the currentaward entry:
           document.getElementById("currentaward").focus();
        },  // end success
        error: function( xhr, textStatus, err )
        {
           //alert( data );
           alert( xhr + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + err );
        } // end error
     }); // end ajax call
  } // end of function: getFirstAward
```

If I uncomment the alert() dialog, all the controls appear correctly. If not, the last four do not. I have tried reiterating that code to see if that helped (setting the value for the different controls, etc.) and it didn't make a difference. I tried using location.reload() and it didn't do any good (whether with the parameter or not: location.reload(true), makes no difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code get executed before page loads completely and missed out few details/value needed for proper code execution. Try the following

```
setTimeout(function() {
    getFirstAward();
}, 0); // try changing the duration from 0 to 100/500 whichever works for u.
```